# Mule devkit Error: [ERROR] Could not create MANIFEST for Studio plugin: Attempt to reopen a file for path MANIFEST.MF

Tags: maven, zip, package, mule

When I run this command:

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false
```

I get this error:

```
...
[INFO] Adding registry bootstrap entry for org.apache.solr.client.solrj.transformers.ORDEREnumTransformer as ORDEREnumTransformer
[ERROR] Could not create MANIFEST for Studio plugin: Attempt to reopen a file for path MANIFEST.MF
[ERROR] error on execute: An error ocurred while the DevKit was generating Java code. Check the logs for further details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.772s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 13 20:48:10 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-maven-plugin:3.3.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project mule-module-solr: An error ocurred while the DevKit was generating Java code. Check the logs for further details. -> [Help 1]
...
```

Some odd things:

1. If I change from `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false` to `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=true`, but then it doesn't finish its task.
2. I'm starting from a working project fork [here](https://github.com/ttennebkram/mule-module-solr), where I am able to run the full command with `...skip=false`.  I've only added one additional class to `src/main/java/org/mule/modules`, which I believe follows the annotation patterns, and is much simpler.  (can't really share that code yet)  And added 2 dependencies: `httpclient` and `jackson-databind`. It goes through all its checks for both classes, `[INFO] Searching for classes annotated with @Connector` and then `[INFO] Validating MyXyzConnector class`

Questions / things I've considered:

- I think `-Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false` tells it to generate a .zip file?
- If so, is that required to deploy?
- I assume the .zip file wants to have a manifest?
- The part of the error about the MANIFEST file `...Attempt to reopen a file ...` sounds like a concurrency issue???
- I don't see any mention of a manifest in my pom.xml, nor that of the working pom.xml
- There's some talk online that later versions of devkit had issues and that people should back-rev to 3.3.0, but I checked and that **is** what I'm using in pom.xml `<mule.devkit.version>3.3.0</mule.devkit.version>`

Not sure where to go next.

Comment: Confirmed that -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false does generate target/UpdateSite.zip, which is used as a local site to install software via the Help menu in Studio (not news to experienced Mule developers, but "for the record")

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that error is caused by having more than one connector class in your project.  You can have more than one .java file, but I think only 1 can have the `@Connector` annotation.

I started by temporarily removing my new class, and then creating a minimal `HelloWorldConnector.java` connector *(shown below)*.  It also generated the same MANIFEST error.  When I renamed the original working `SolrConnector.java` to `SolrConnector.java-MOVED` and reran the build with `-Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false`, it worked fine and generated the `target/UpdateSite.zip` file.  I really unhelpful error message...

**HelloWorldConnector.java** minimal connector test:

```
package org.mule.modules;

import org.mule.api.ConnectionException;
import org.mule.api.ConnectionExceptionCode;
import org.mule.api.annotations.*;
import org.mule.api.annotations.display.FriendlyName;
import org.mule.api.annotations.display.Placement;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Default;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Payload;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Module for debugging
 *
 * {@sample.xml ../../../doc/solr-connector.xml.sample solr:config}
 *
 * @author Mark
 */
@Connector(name = "hello", schemaVersion = "1.0.0", friendlyName = "Hello", minMuleVersion = "3.3.0")
public class HelloWorldConnector {

    /**
     * Connect to the Solr Server using commons http client gateway.
     */
    @Connect
    public synchronized void connectHello() throws ConnectionException {
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from the server, nothing special needed at this time.
     */
    @Disconnect
    public synchronized void disconnectHello() {
    }

    /**
     * Identify the connection.
     *
     * @return null, not used at this time.
     */
    @ConnectionIdentifier
    public String connectionIdentifierHello() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Validate the connection by sending a ping request.
     *
     * @return true if the ping call succeeds, false otherwise.
     */
    @ValidateConnection
    public boolean isConnectedHello() {
        return true;
    }
}
```